OpenSearch custom config settings are not seen in the opensearch dashboard
I'm new to OpenSearch, and I'm trying to configure OpenSearch using few customizations. First thing is I want to setup a different authentication method using OpenID Connect instead of using the internal user database file. As a start, I tried taking copies of different security config files such as config.yml and internal_users.yml to try some customizations. I have commented out all other authc options in config.yml and kept only basic_internal_auth_domain. And I added a new user with a password in the internal_users.yml as well. Then I mounted the customized config files to opensearch-nodes through docker-compose.yml. When I start the cluster using docker-compose up, The dashboard gets up and running, but I cant log-in with the new user credentials I added. Also after logging with the admin credentials, I can still see the authentication methods in the security settings even though I have removed them in the mounted config.yml file. I checked whether the files are correctly mounted using a bash shell inside the containers, they are correctly mounted. Can someone explain whether I have doing these customizations wrong? Following are the parts of the files I modified.
config.yml
config:
  dynamic:
    http:
      anonymous_auth_enabled: false
     authc:
      basic_internal_auth_domain:
        description: "Authenticate via HTTP Basic against internal users database"
        http_enabled: true
        transport_enabled: true
        order: 0
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: true
        authentication_backend:
          type: intern

internal_users.yml
# Define your internal users here

## Demo users

customadmin:
  hash: "$2a$12$wzKZMYOQZ0KE8WsgfXqQxuvflKlzmSTprlPZrAaJDcXnhjgmrVZNm"
  reserved: false
  backend_roles:
  - "admin"
  description: `"Demo admin user for customization purpose"

...

docker-compose.yaml
services:
  opensearch-node1: # This is also the hostname of the container within the Docker network (i.e. https://opensearch-node1/)
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.11.1 # Use the 2.11.1 version of OpenSearch for all nodes
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster # Name the cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1 # Name the node that will run in this container
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # Nodes to look for when discovering the cluster
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # Nodes eligibile to serve as cluster manager
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # Disable JVM heap memory swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # Set min and max JVM heap sizes to at least 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1 # Set memlock to unlimited (no soft or hard limit)
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # Maximum number of open files for the opensearch user - set to at least 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data # Creates volume called opensearch-data1 and mounts it to the container
      - ./node-configs/opensearch-security/config.yml:/usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch-security/config.yml # Mount the custom OpenSearch Security configuration file for AuthN and AuthZ
      - ./node-configs/opensearch-security/internal_users.yml:/usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch-security/internal_users.yml # Mount the custom OpenSearch Security internal users configuration file
    ports:
      - 9200:9200 # REST API
      - 9600:9600 # Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net # All of the containers will join the same Docker bridge network


# same with node 2 


As OpenSearch docs specifies, this can be solved by running the securityadmin.sh script inside each container as follows;
cd ./plugins/opensearch-security/tools

chmod +x ./securityadmin.sh

./securityadmin.sh -cd ../../../config/opensearch-security/ -icl -nhnv   -cacert ../../../config/root-ca.pem   -cert ../../../config/kirk.pem   -key ../../../config/kirk-key.pem

Could not find a way to automate this step without going inside of each opensearch-node container.
